# How to get multiple inputs in single line

Tags: python-3.x

I want the user to enter a number. Then add certain values to a list whose length would be equal to the number entered previously.

```
players=int(input("Enter players:"))  
"""First input i.e. length of list"""
home = [int(home) for players in input("Enter home team runs: ").split()]  """Values to be captured on the list"""

Enter players: 3 

Enter home team runs: 10 20 60
```

I get the error message:

> NameError: name 'home' is not defined

Comment: Where do you think `home` was defined?

Comment: A much better design would read inputs as command-line arguments or perhaps from a file so you can build automation around this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, You need to define home before using it, hence the error `NameError: name 'home' is not defined`
Also your statement `players in input("Enter home team runs: ").split()` doesn't make sense. You are overwriting `players` variable here, also your loop variable is `players` but you are referring to `home`

A better approach would be

```
#Take players as input
players=int(input("Enter players:"))

#Take runs as input
runs = input("Enter home team runs: ")

#Make home list via list-comprehension
home = [int(run) for run in runs.split()]
print(home)
```

The output will be

```
Enter players:3
Enter home team runs: 10 20 60
[10, 20, 60]
```

Comment: How will this limit the input in "home" variable to the integer in "players" variable??

Comment: I didn't understand your question @Asheet_s   sorry!

Comment: If players are 3, then length of home list should be 3.

Comment: The list length is 3, however I am using runs as the list to score home team runs [10, 20, 60] @Asheet_s

Comment: Hi @Asheet_s, if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to the answer, else please ask if you have any questions for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
players = int(input("Enter players:"))
home = [int(players) for players in input("Enter home team runs: ").split()]
print(home)
```